# ngstorage's $localStorage still available in angular after deleting browser data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, local-storage, ng-storage

I am using `ngStorage` for storing data in local storage. I am facing this weird issue where, when I am deleting the localstorage from the browser, my website's user doesn't get logged out on url change.
Here's the code that keeps the check whether the localstorage exists or not and then does the appropriate route:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
              //it always by passes this
                if (!$localStorage.currentUser) {

                    $location.path('/login');

                }

            });
```

Only when I refresh the page, it automatically routes to the `login` page, or else it continues to go on any route in the website and that too without having the localstorage value.

Why's this happening ? please help me

Comment: how are you deleting the $localStorage.currentUse?

Comment: I am deleting it directly from the browser's localstorage section.

Comment: Share your code where you are deleting it

Comment: @ShashankVivek, I am deleting it manually from the browser and then performing a route. There's no code for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//Checks if currentUser property still exists
if (!$localStorage.hasOwnProperty("currentUser")) {
      $location.path('/login');
}
```

Comment: Just checked it. Yes it still exists even after deleting the localstorage value manually .

Comment: How did you set your `currentUser`? by doing this -> `$localStorage.currentUser = "test"` ?

Comment: Yes. $localStorage.currentUser = { username: username, token: response.data.id_token };

Comment: You sure? tried it in my end it gets `undefined` when directly deleted it in the browser

Comment: yes sir, I am sure. I have checked it many times
Just to be sure, are you refreshing the page after deleting the value.? because refreshing the page gives the desired result i.e undefined and thus redirects to `/login`

Comment: No i didn't refresh, and when i deleted it and navigate to other page it gets `undefined`

Comment: Same as what you did, maybe you have other operations that prevents `currentUser` to be deleted, try to find it

Comment: No sir, I don't think so. I'll list down all the operation performed using ngStorage in my edit.

Comment: Just to add one more thing. I have just tested the same code with default `window.localStorage` and plugin `angular-local-storage`. It works like charm. But seems like there's some issue with `ngStorage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170419/discussion-between-steve-and-john-velasquez).

Comment: I had just replaced all code with `angular-local-storage` and it works fine but not with ngStorage.